# Assistance with Access search field

Tags: ms-access

I have a search field that works on my other forms and I am trying to use it for this purpose.

I track reported numbers for my providers in hours.

I have several provider and will be giving this database to other sections so I cannot make is specific to my providers.

My SearchResults field selects the record when clicked on.

Here are my two problems:

1. I need the SearchResults field to display "Provider", "Data_Month", and "Data_year". I can't figure that out.
2. When the name is the same, it sets the month to the same month for each entry.

This is the row source for the SearchResults field:

```
SELECT [Provider_Time_Query].[Provider] FROM Provider_Time_Query WHERE ((([Provider_Time_Query].[Provider]) Like "*" & Forms![Provider Time]!SrchText & "*")) ORDER BY [Provider_Time_Query].[Provider];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I'm going in the wrong direction, please help me find my way! Thank you!!!

Comment: You say SearchResults `field` but you really mean `combobox`? You want combobox dropdown list to show 3 columns: `Provider, Data_Month, Data_Year`? Where should the month and year values come from? For item 2, expression in textbox can reference columns of combobox or use code to save value to field.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!! I have it set to a list box. I said SearchResults only because that's what I named it. I have two other 3 fields labeled: Provider, Data_Month, and Data_Year that are all text fields. So would a Combobox be more appropriate for this? And is there a way to change my row source to include the other 2 fields?

Comment: I found my problem with the second part. Becuase I'm searching for the name, it only pulls data from the name that come first in the list. in the table I have 3 entries for Watson with 3 different ID Numbers. The Listbox show 3 Watsons but each one has the data of the one first in the list. Now I can't figure out how to fix that lol

Comment: I got it all figured out. I was converting a text box to a list box and adding a row source. I just created a search query and now it's working as expected ha ha